# powershell script isn't working, but shows no errors. Find all .xml files in a directory, do a replace on some text, move to different directory

Tags: powershell

The powershell script errored out a few times b/c of missed commas and the like. Now it appears to run with no errors, but nothing happens - files aren't moved, text isn't replaced.

FYI, I got the replace to work by itself - it scanned all the .XML files and replaced that tiny string with the bigger one. The replace does include new lines and spaces as one needs in XML, but I simplified it in this sample so it was easier to read.

As always, all help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: SOLUTION ADDED. Thank you, TheMadTechnician

```
$CurrFilePath = "C:\Folder\Path1"
$TransIncludePattern = "*.xml"
$ProcessFilePath = "C:\Folder\Path2"

try #Get-ChildItem -Path $CurrFilePath\* -Include $TransIncludePattern | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object  
    { 
    $CurrFileName = Get-childitem -Path $CurrFilePath\* -Include $TransIncludePattern;
    $CurrFileName | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
        ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host "Changing file $_";
            $content = (Get-Content $_);
            $newContent = $content | ForEach-Object {
                    
                    ($_-replace '</InitgPty>', '<Id> <OrgId> <Id>DAMNID</Id> </OrgId> </Id></InitgPty>'); 
      
      }
            $newContent | Set-Content $_; #or [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($_, $newContent) :)

            Write-Host "File Changed: $_";
        }
        
        Write-Host "Has DamnID";
        
        Move-Item -CurrFileName $file -Destination $ProcessFilePath;
        
        exit 0;
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_;
}
```

Working script:

```
$CurrFilePath = "C:\Folder\Path1"
$TransIncludePattern = "*.xml"
$ProcessFilePath = "C:\Folder\Path2"

try #Get-ChildItem -Path $CurrFilePath\* -Include $TransIncludePattern | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object  
    { 
    $CurrFileName = Get-childitem -Path $CurrFilePath\* -Include $TransIncludePattern;
    $CurrFileName | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
        ForEach-Object {
            
            $content = (Get-Content $_);
            $newContent = $content | ForEach-Object {
                    
                    ($_-replace '</InitgPty>', '<Id> <OrgId> <Id>DAMNID</Id> </OrgId> </Id></InitgPty>'); 
      
      }
            $NewContent = Set-Content -Path $_ -Value $newContent;

          
        }
        
        
        Move-Item -Path .\*.xml -Destination $ProcessFilePath;
        
        exit 0;
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_;
}
```

Comment: `-CurrFileName` doesn't sound like a valid parameter

Comment: Up to which part does the code do what it is supposed to? Try adding `Write-Host` lines that output variables and check if the values meet your expectations. It can help to break down a long pipeline into smaller pieces and output intermediate results to verify them.

Comment: "nothing happens"... something happens... the code is run. I suggest you learn to debug and step through the code and work out what _does_ happen

Comment: zett42, I got the replace to work in its own, separate, powershell script. Now I'm trying to combine everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lose context of `$_`  when you go to `Set-Content`.  `$newContent = Set-Content $_` I assume the `$_` is supposed to reference the file name, but at that point it contains the modified content of the file. Try `Set-Content -Path $_ -Value $newContent` instead on that line.

Then when you move the file the parameter `-CurrFileName` is not a valid parameter. Instead use `Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination $ProcessFilePath`

Comment: WOOHOO, looks like it's working somewhat! It's an equal sign, not a pipe (as you know!). I'll  keep banging at it!!

Comment: IT'S 100% working! The other line I modified was the move-item. `Move-Item -Path .\*.xml -Destination $ProcessFilePath`  I can' t thank you enough!!!!!!